# Collect input with Linux Dialogs

Tags: linux, dialog, redhat, centos5

I found out about Dialogs, so I'm updating menus today. So far, so good.

I came to one where I need to collect a user's input.

I have

```
dialog --title " INPUT FILE NAME: " --inputbox "$(ls)" 30 40 2> answer
```

This will send the users input to a file named "answer"

I have tried

```
dialog --title " INPUT FILE NAME: " --inputbox "$(ls)" 30 40 2> $answer
```

but that doesnt seem to do anything.

I tried

```
answer=$(dialog --title " INPUT FILE NAME: " --inputbox "$(ls)" 30 40 2)
```

but there is some kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html) (for dialog) tells the story:

> Some  widgets,  e.g.,  checklist,  will  write text to **dialog**'s output.
>   Normally that is the standard error, but there are options for changing
>   this:  "**`--output-fd`**", "**`--stderr`**" and "**`--stdout`**".  No text is written if
>   the Cancel button (or ESC) is pressed; **dialog** exits immediately in that.

The reason dialog uses the standard error by default for its output is that it uses the curses/ncurses library, which normally prints *its* output (for the screen updates) to the standard output.  To change dialog's behavior (and write to the standard output), use the "**`--stdout`**" option.

Interestingly (though it may appear an obvious problem to solve because it complicates scripting), the [Xdialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/) program implemented this option first; it seemed a *Good Thing* to add to dialog (see [changelog](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/CHANGES.html#t20000702)).

Answer (score 0):

Done

```
dialog --title " INPUT FILE NAME: " --inputbox "$(ls )" 30 40 2>answer
ans=$(cat answer)
rm answer
```